# In-Store pickup not fully available in ATG reference store?

Tags: atg

I had a question on in-store pickup. I see that there is support for it in the CRS module (it has GeoLocatorService, GeoLocatorDroplet etc), but don't see any buttons or JSPs that display or let you use it out of the box. On the other hand, commerce service center has this functionality fully exposed, with in-store pickup buttons, popup widgets to search for stores and shopping carts showing store pickup line items etc. Looks like the web stores would need this functionality exclusively coded, which would involve creating JSPs and components as required.

Is there something I can copy over from CSC (commerce service center) that will enable store pickup in web module (store US or home US etc?) very quickly? Please let me know. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to capture payment and collect from store , or reserve in store and pay when you pick up the item.

In both the cases your DOM (distributed Order Management) and WMS (warehouse management system) has important role to play. ATG can lookup the selected store inventory , both locally (location repository) or using realtime webservice interface to the system that manages your global inventory.

In all cases ATG will be able to capture the order, but this order has to be handled by DOM in such a way that its routed to local store for fulfillment. If by any chance this order is not available in local store, your DOM/ WMS system should be able to send order item to local store from warehouse or from another store.

Walmart has both the functionality available (click to collect and reserve and pay at store) , walmart has proprietary software DOM3 which eventually addresses these interfaces.

Please realize ATG is just your online order capture system, Click to Collect and any 'commerce anywhere' functionality must be offered by your DOM. if this is offered by your DOM , all you need to do is exchange messages with DOM to achieve this.

I am not sure if this answers your question, but its not recommended to over engineer ATG , and ATG should follow the heart beat of your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In Store Pickup - often called Click & Collect - has not been implemented as a feature in the CRS. It is also not in CSC either.

You will need to do quite a bit of customisation to support it.

The feature that is part of CRS is Store Locator. This allows you to find and view details of physical stores.

You can use this as a basis to build Click & Collect functionality.

Assuming that other back-end systems can handle it, and your business is set up to consider things like promotions, pricing etc. for a Click & Collect proposition...

Basically, you will need to implement a new Shipping Method, a New subtype of Hardgood Shipping Group that can use a Store Code instead of a Customer Address, as well as the UI to support choosing a store during checkout.

Depending on how sophisticated your multi channel requirements are, you may need to modify the Inventory Manager to accommodate knowing local stock in store as well as central stock.

Other shipping related entities may need to change to represent any new statuses such as Arrived in Store or Ready for Collection.

If you are using ATG Fulfilment, you may need to change messaging there to accommodate, say, conveying a store code instead of a delivery address to fulfillers and carriers.